# Qt error with reMarkable tablet app

Tags: qt

I have a [reMarkable](http://remarkable.com) tablet , which I mostly love except for the lack of linux support (surprising given it is a linux-based OS). However, I've managed to find a version of a linux application that is now unofficial. [This github](https://github.com/ptman/remarkable-docker) is actually a Qt docker app, but if you look in the code for the 'Dockerfile' you can find where to download the app, which is apparently still on the server even though there's not a link from the main web page. Anyway, I downloaded it and got it mostly working, figuring out a few dependencies based on same Dockerfile code. But, I can't seem to get file dialogs to work, which is the main reason for using the app.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: No native FileDialog implementation available.
Qt Labs Platform requires Qt Widgets on this setup.
Add 'QT += widgets' to .pro and create QApplication in main().
```

I'm not a Qt developer, so I'm lost. I'd love to get this to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the .pro file of you project you should add this line `QT += widgets`
or just add `widgets` to the line with `QT += ...`

Comment: This is not my project, this is a binary. I tried adding it in the same directory but to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do sorry. Maybe you can ask to the person who did the binary to add it and send it to you again. If it's an open source application you can get the sources and recompile it by yourself, else either it's a binary you are allowed to have and you could ask or not then you may have licensing problem by using it.

Answer (score 1):

Qt can use native file dialogs on some platforms, and will fall back to its own implementation if none is available. But that requires that the application is built including the QtWidgets module, and using a QApplication.

If you don't have the source code of the app and a possiblity to rebuild it, there's no chance to fix this from a binary

Comment: Oh I see. I guess I'm screwed then. Thanks for answering, I will now stop wasting my time on this.